# Why do enumerable methods work in some environments and not others?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my debugger:

```
(rdb:1) [5,4,3].each_cons(2) {|e| p e}
nil
```

In rails console:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :019 > [5,4,3].each_cons(2) {|e| p e}
[5, 4]
[4, 3]
 => nil
```

Comment: I don't know what's going on, but can you print out `RUBY_VERSION` for the debugger and for Rails console?

Answer (score 3):

It's probably because you are using different Ruby versions, or that Rails monkey patches it.

Comment: `each_cons` was available without requiring anything since ruby 1.8.7. If his `rdb` session used ruby 1.8.6 calling `each_cons` would cause a NoMethodError. There is no ruby version in which `each_cons` would just return `nil` without invoking the block when called on a non-empty array.